# How to run pipenv-ed scripts inside Airflow?

Tags: airflow, virtualenv, pipenv

I want to replace cron-scheduling with airflow.

My current setup:

- 50+ python-programs
- each runs in its on virtualenv
- and is executed from shell-scripts `pipenv run <>` which are triggered from cron-daemon

My problem is that I manually have to maintain the 'correct' order in which programs are being executed.

Now I am switching over to airflow. Unfortunately I haven't yet figured out what the preferred way is to execute the python programs within their virtualenv.

Currently I am considering using the BashOperator and hardcoding the path/to/virtualenv for each script. That seems like an unnecessary amount of effort and high maintenance.

Have you had a similar problem? What would you do in my shoes?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach you can follow here is create an image per python script or scripts if they share requirements and then use the DockerOperator.

I leave you here a video explaining what is and how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdW2ZHHJWeo